# Reverse geocoding without showing Google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

Google says

> The Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited.

about geocoding API, what is the situation about reverse geocoding if I don't use google maps in my app?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about terms of use, not programming

Comment: OpenStreetMap could be a possible alternative for you.

Answer (score 2):

Since reverse-geocoding is the part of Geocoding API, you must observe that rule.